# Multicast packets not received on windows

Tags: java, windows, udp, multicast

I'm playing with UDP multicast and I've come across a strange situation where I can't understand what's happening.

Here is the scenario:

The machines are on a network made up of 3 TP-Link Deco XE75 (forming a mesh) and several switches.

Deco #1 is the main element and it is wired to the WAN.
It is also wired to a switch that, in turn, is wired to Deco #2, Deco #3 and 192.168.68.200.

192.168.68.61 is connected via WiFi to Deco #2.

**Physical machine 192.168.68.61**

- bind: 0.0.0.0:1234
- join: 224.0.1.187 (IGMP confirmed by netsh and wireshark)
- join: 239.0.0.1 (IGMP confirmed by netsh and wireshark)

**Physical machine 192.168.68.200**

- bind: 0.0.0.0:12345
- join: 224.0.1.187 (IGMP confirmed by netsh and wireshark)
- join: 239.0.0.1 (IGMP confirmed by netsh and wireshark)

This is what happens:

- **message A** (source: 192.168.68.61:1234 - target: 224.0.1.187:12345) 
   **NOT RECEIVED** by 192.168.68.200 (not present even on Wireshark)
- **message B** (source: 192.168.68.61:1234 - target: 239.0.0.1:12345) 
   **RECEIVED** by 192.168.68.200
- **message C** (source: 192.168.68.200:12345 - target: 224.0.1.187:1234)

   **RECEIVED** by 192.168.68.61
- **message D** (source: 192.168.68.200:12345 - target: 239.0.0.1:1234)

   **RECEIVED** by 192.168.68.61

The only message that is not received is the message A

Here are some screens (messages A and B):

[image: 192.168.68.61]

[image: 192.168.68.200]

Maybe is the Deco mesh blocking multicast **one way only** and for **a specific group only**?

Comment: That multicast group is assigned to a different use. You cannot just grab a multicast group in the Internetwork Control Block (224.0.1.0 - 224.0.1.255 (224.0.1/24)) range. You should use multicast groups in the 239.0.0.0-239.255.255.255 Organization-Local Scope range.

Comment: Please see the updated answer. However I didn't know about specific uses of multicast groups, I should gather some info. Thanks

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xhtml

Comment: Are both devices on the same switch? There is a problem with some switches and the DHCP snooping of IGMP joins if there are separate switches.

Comment: No, they aren't. There's a mesh. Details on update. It feels a little strange though that packets are blocked one-way only and only for CoAP group (other groups, even on the same block, works fine...)

Comment: It really depends on the groups used. Link-local groups are not blocked by the DHCP snooping problem, while other groups may be. If by mesh, you mean Wi-Fi, that presents other problems with multicast, such as broadcast and multicast frames are sent at the slowest speed configured on the devices (even down to 1 Mbps if allowed on the device) because they must be able to reach distant devices, which is why streaming application do not work well on Wi-Fi. A switch doing IGMP snooping will not automatically send multicast frames to adjacent switches.